# Can I do like su.pr: map an external domain to one of my subdomain on shared hosting service?

Tags: domain

su.pr (from stumbleupon) allows to use my own short URL (i.e. www.mydomain.com/ab123) instead of stumbleupon branding.

What if I do have some kind of service I want to offer to other webmasters and allow them to use their own domain ?

Is this possible on a shared hosting ?

Comment: Though @josh already answered and thus understood your question: can you extend on this a bit? Like for http://su.pr/1TTQbW (which is http://www.stumbleupon.com/s/#1TTQbW/letsbefriends.blogspot.com/) you would use `www.mydomain.com/ab123` instead of `su.pr/1TTQbW`? (But that domain would then *not* remain visible in the location bar, would it?) Are you sure you're not referring to something like `ab123.mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

If "shared hosting" is defined as a service you're purchasing from an ISP where they host your domain and 49 others peoples' on one web server, then no, it is not possible.

If by "shared hosting" you mean you have a server you configure and you want a single server to respond to each of those domains differently, then yes: you would set up a site to respond to all HTTP requests on an IP and you would analyze the HTTP Header information passed to your web application from the web server (IIS and Apache both handle this similarly.)

Comment: True, though surely *some* shared hosting companies allow you to add *any* (sub) domain you like, even if not known in their DNS. Next, if the domain owner sets its DNS records to point that (sub) domain to that specific shared hosting server, then `abc.mydomain.com` could in fact show something hosted at `example.com`. But, unlike your second option, that would require a lot of (manual) configuration. Some hosters might even offer an API for that, like http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Application_programming_interface (which does not support adding domains yet).